# raw socket send two packets on a virtual Network

Tags: c, sockets, ethernet, raw-ethernet

I've a problem with my sendto function in my code, when I try to send a raw ethernet packet.

I use a Ubuntu 12.04.01 LTS, with two tap devices connected over two vde_switches and a dpipe

Example:

my send programm create the packet like below, the programm is binded by the socket from tap0 and send the packet to tap1. On tap1 one receiver wait for all packets on socket.

My raw ethernet packet looks so:

*destination Addr* __*_*_*source Addr* __*_*__*_*___  *type/length* __*_**data*

*00:00:01:00:00:00****_*__***00:00:01:00:00:01****_*___** length in Byte***_*_***some data*

Example packet to send:

```
00:00:01:00:00:00 00:00:01:00:00:01 (length in byte) (Message)test
```

but my programm generate two packets, when I look in wireshark:

first packet is an IPX packet and [Malformed Packet] and looks like in hex (data = test)

```
00 04 00 01 00 06 00 00 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 74 65 73 74 00

Linux cooked capture

Packet type: sent by us (4)

Link-layer address type: 1

Link-layer address length: 6

Source: 00:00:01:00:00:01

Protocol: Raw 802.3 (0x0001)

[Malformed Packet: IPX]
```

second packet unknown protocol

```
00 00 00 01 00 06 00 00 01 00 00 01 00 00 31 00 74 65 73 74 00

Linux cooked capture

Packet type: Unicast to us (0)

Link-layer address type: 1

Link-layer address length: 6

Source: 00:00:01:00:00:01

Protocol: Unknown (0x3100)

Data

Data: 7465737400

[Length: 5]
```

outcut from my source code

```
sock_desc = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));


/*struct for sending*/
    sock_addr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sock_addr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_802_3);
    sock_addr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(argv[1]);
    sock_addr.sll_hatype = ARPHRD_ETHER; //Ethernet 10Mbps
    sock_addr.sll_pkttype = PACKET_HOST; // Paket zu irgendjemand
    sock_addr.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN; //6 Oktets in einer ethernet addr
    /*MAC Length 8 Oktets*/
    sock_addr.sll_addr[0] = frame.src_mac[0];
    sock_addr.sll_addr[1] = frame.src_mac[1];
    sock_addr.sll_addr[2] = frame.src_mac[2];
    sock_addr.sll_addr[3] = frame.src_mac[3];
    sock_addr.sll_addr[4] = frame.src_mac[4];
    sock_addr.sll_addr[5] = frame.src_mac[5];
    /*not in use*/  
    sock_addr.sll_addr[6] = 0x00;
    sock_addr.sll_addr[7] = 0x00;

    memset(buffer, '0', sizeof(char)*ETH_FRAME_LEN);
    /*set the frame header*/

    /*build RAW Ethernet packet*/
    buffer[0] = frame.dest_mac[0];
    buffer[1] = frame.dest_mac[1];
    buffer[2] = frame.dest_mac[2];
    buffer[3] = frame.dest_mac[3];
    buffer[4] = frame.dest_mac[4];
    buffer[5] = frame.dest_mac[5];

    buffer[6] = frame.src_mac[0];
    buffer[7] = frame.src_mac[1];
    buffer[8] = frame.src_mac[2];
    buffer[9] = frame.src_mac[3];
    buffer[10] = frame.src_mac[4];
    buffer[11] = frame.src_mac[5];

    while(frame.data[0] != '*'){
      printf("Input: ");
      scanf("%s", frame.data);

      tempLength = 0;
      while(frame.data[tempLength] != '\0'){
      tempLength++;
      }
      input = 0;
      for(sendLen = 14;sendLen <= (14+tempLength);sendLen++){
          buffer[sendLen] = frame.data[input];
          input++;
      }

      sprintf(convLen,"%x", (14 + input));
      buffer[12] = convLen[0];
      buffer[13] = convLen[1];

      length_in_byte = sendto(sock_desc, buffer, 14+input,0,(struct sockaddr*) &sock_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
      if(length_in_byte <= 0){
        printf("Error beim Senden");
      }else{
            printf("\n");
            printf("src: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\t->\tdest: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",frame.src_mac[0],frame.src_mac[1],frame.src_mac[2],frame.src_mac[3],frame.src_mac[4],frame.src_mac[5],frame.dest_mac[0],frame.dest_mac[1],frame.dest_mac[2],frame.dest_mac[3],frame.dest_mac[4],frame.dest_mac[5]);
            printf("Data: %s\n", frame.data);
      }
  }
```

please i need some help to find my mistake.

Thank you forward.

Comment: There is too little information here. Could you try to make the a complete, compilable, consice example that exhibits your problem. Do you send using a RAW or DGRAM packet socket? Notice that PACKET_OTHERHOST has no meaning for outgoing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I see why my receiver receiv two packets. The first packet ist the send by us packet and the second is the Unicast to us. The problem I don't need the first packet to receive. I have test my code and have one capture with the two packets as example.

First frame in hex code from Wireshark:

```
0004 0001 0006 0000010000020000 0060 the message
```

Second frame:

```
0000 0001 0006 0000010000020000 1234 the message
```

This is Linux cooked capture an means:

```
2 Bytes packet typ // 0 = To us; 1 = Broadcast; 2 = Multicast; 3 = from somebody to somebody; 4 = sent by us

2 Bytes LINUX ARPHDR_ value
2 Bytes Link layer addr. lenght
8 Bytes source address
2 Bytes Ethernet protocol //e.g. 1 Novell 802.3 without 802.2 header; 4 frames with 802.2 header
```

My questions:

First is it possible to filter or ignore the first packet?

Second why contains the first packet the protocol typ from the send structur and the second packet the protocol typ from buffer?

Example:

For the first packet

```
sock_addr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
sock_addr.sll_protocol = htons(0x0060);
sock_addr.sll_ifindex = 3;
sock_addr.sll_hatype = ARPHRD_ETHER;
sock_addr.sll_pkttype = PACKET_HOST;
sock_addr.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN; 
/*MAC Length 8 Oktets*/
sock_addr.sll_addr[0] = 0x00;
sock_addr.sll_addr[1] = 0x00;
sock_addr.sll_addr[2] = 0x01
sock_addr.sll_addr[3] = 0x00;
sock_addr.sll_addr[4] = 0x00;
sock_addr.sll_addr[5] = 0x02;
/*not in use*/  
sock_addr.sll_addr[6] = 0x00;
sock_addr.sll_addr[7] = 0x00;
```

for second packet the buffer like 802.3 frame

```
buffer[0-5] = 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x03 // Destination address
buffer[6-11] = 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x02 // Source address
buffer[12-13] = 0x12 0x34 // Protocol dummy typ
```

My receiver can capture the first packet without a connection between two vde_switches and when I connect the switches with dpipe and vde_plug can I capture the second packet too.

Comment: I suggest you make this a new question. Adding a new question as an answer is not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Are you capturing from all network devices? That would explain why you get the packet twice. Try capturing from one device. To capture just the "arriving" end, dont capture on the device sending out the packet, just the one receiving it.

Comment: That is a snipped from my receiver code:  create socket: sock_desc = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)); bind socket on one device: setsockopt(sock_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &sock_in.ifr_name, strlen(sock_in.ifr_name)); and receive packets: recvfrom(sock_desc, buffer, ETH_FRAME_LEN,0,NULL,NULL);

Comment: Just ignore packets of type 4, "sent by us". I think that is the packet before its going out on the wire. The _man 7 packet_ states that for SOCK_RAW the buffer is used as is, so things you set in struct sockaddr_ll, that are also in the ethernet frame, are ignored. So the second packet is the actual real one.

Comment: I think the same about the type 4 packet.  When I watch in wireshark on one specific device, I can see only one packet in the Ethernet II format and this is the real packet over the wire. Can you give me a example that the socket ignore the wrong packets? I've try the recvfrom funktion with a similar configuration in the example above.

Comment: Instead of ETH_P_ALL, open the packet socket for the protocol type you are going to use (e.g. 0x1234 or whatever). You could also try using [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) on the capturing end.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us the lines dealing with the socket creation operation.
I assume you have created your socket like that :

```
int socket = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_IP)
```

You are right when you build the ethernet header (by the way you should use instead struct ethhdr, it's cleaner).
After that you send your data, without putting L4 header and L3 header.... It's normal that your code doesn't work.
I assume you now the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).
If it's not the case read the paper before reading the next text.

So when you want to create a RAW packet, you have many things to do before.
For example if you want to use TCP/IP protocol you will have to do the next operation

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/ip.h>
 #include <netinet/tcp.h>
 #DEFINE SIZEMAX 1000
 int main() {
 char buffer[65535] // MDU
 // CREATE YOUR SOCKET 
 int socket = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_RAW) ; 
 // You can also specify some opt to your socket but I let you done your own stuffs
 struct ethhdr * ethdr ; 
 struct iphdr * iph ; 
 struct tcphdr * tcph; 
 // Fill all the fields of these last structures (i can't do it for you too long). 
 // Fill the buffer
 memcpy(buffer,ethdr,sizeof(struct ethhdr)) ; 
 // Deplace it to the good addr
 buffer = buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr) ; 
 memcpy(buffer,iph,sizeof(struct iphdr)) ; 
 buffer = buffer + sizeof(struct iphdr)) ; 
 memcpy(buffer,tcph,sizeof(struct tcphdr)) ; 
 printf("your entry : \n") ; 
 char * entry = malloc(SIZEMAX) ; 
 sncanf("%s",entry,100) ; 
 buffer = buffer+ 100 ; 
 memcpy(buffer,entry,100) ; 
 int size_send = sendto(socket,.......) ;  
 if(size_send =< 0) 
   perror("error sending data") ; 

 return 0 ; 

}
```

This is pseudo-code but it tell you how to send raw packet.
This paper will do the work for you :
[RAW Socket TCP/IP](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html)

Hope it will help you

Anthony

Comment: Hi Anthony, thank you for your answer, but I've a little problem. I don't use network devices with a IP Address, my communication should work over tap devices. I've create a thread in a Ubuntu forum [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322904/isolated-ethernet) and my problem is how can I communicat with the Ethernet packet over the tap devices on one host. Best regards Patrick

Comment: Hi I'm sorry I had misunderstood your question. I've never used TUN/TAP network, so I can't help you. I hope you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is missing the ethernet "packet type ID field". See [struct ethhdr in if_ether.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.10.2/include/uapi/linux/if_ether.h#L133). Now you put `convLen` where the proto should be. It probably matches the proto number of IPX. Try setting it to something (eg ETH_P_IP) or test what happens when you set it to zero.

I understand you want to make your own protocol and are using the field after the ethernet addresses for the length. However I do suggest you keep at least the ethernet level header standards compliant and build your own on top of that (in the ethernet frame payload). Otherwise youll get problems with tools(like wireshark) and device drivers that try to parse the ethernet headers.

As to why you send two packets, I think the reason lies in the way you scanf input from the user. The while loop is peculiar. I suggest trying to send some data with a fixed input, eg `char msg[] = "Test";`

Sorry if the answer is vague. It is difficult to help you, since your code is not complete and I can not test it.